# Can you animate a SwiftUI View on disappear?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `View` which has a custom animation that runs `onAppear`. I am trying to get the view to animate `onDisappear` too but it just immediately vanishes.

The below example reproduces the problem - the `MyText` view should slide in from the left and slide out to the right. The `id` modifier is used to ensure a new view is rendered each time the value changes, and I have confirmed that both `onAppear` and `onDisappear` are indeed called each time, but the animation `onDisappear` never visibly runs. How can I achieve this?

```swift
struct Survey: View {
  @State private var id = 0

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      MyText(text: "\(id)").id(id)

      Button("Increment") {
        self.id += 1
      }
    }
  }

  struct MyText: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = -100
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
      return Text(text)
        .offset(x: offset)
        .onAppear() {
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
            self.offset = 0
          }
        }
        .onDisappear() {
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
            self.offset = 100
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you wanted transition, something like

[image: demo]

**Update:** re-tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
struct Survey: View {
    @State private var id = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyText(text: "\(id)")

            Button("Increment") {
                self.id += 1
            }
        }
    }

    struct MyText: View {
        var text: String


        var body: some View {
            Text("\(text)").id(text)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .transition(.slide)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done! :) However, about the question, strictly, that's too bad this is still not available natively in SwiftUI in 2021.

Comment: Also as a follow up question... what is the benefit of using a binding in the sub-view? It appears to work either way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it can't work since the .onDisappear modifier is called once the view is hidden.
However there is a nice answer here :
[Is there a SwiftUI equivalent for viewWillDisappear(_:) or detect when a view is about to be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745663/is-there-a-swiftui-equivalent-for-viewwilldisappear-or-detect-when-a-view-is)

Answer (score 0):

maybe sth. like that

```
func disappearAnimation() {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration)) {
        // animation
    }
                  
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animationDuration) {
        dismiss()
    }
    
}
```