# viewWillAppear() or other equivalent in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking for an event in the life-cycle of a view in SwiftUI, that is equivalent to viewWillAppear().
Yes, I know there is an ".OnAppear" in SwiftUI, but that is like viewDidAppear.
Is there a workaround to do get that specific execution time before view is loaded?

Comment: You might be able to fake it by doing something in the `init` of an `ObservableObject` stored as a `@StateObject`. Can you elaborate on your use case or what you're trying to avoid by using `onAppear`?

Comment: Need to load some data and images from web. I'll try your idea. thnx

Comment: But why not use `onAppear` for that? The loading will take a non-zero amount of time, and the returns from any network load like that will be asynchronous, so you aren't blocking anything...

Comment: First, of course it's asynchronous (A Combine's DataTaskPublisher).  Secondly, why do I need to wait for the view to load? I rather start the GET call as soon as possible. What if there will be a lot of data to fetch?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746380/12299030?

Comment: "As soon as possible" is likely to be the difference of milliseconds, if that. SwiftUI views are loaded and put into the view hierarchy sometimes as much as 60-120 times per second. `onAppear` is not likely to give you a big performance hit. I get what you're saying with wanting to accomplish it quickly, but it's likely to be an order (or many orders) of magnitude smaller than the time the network calls take. The amount of data doesn't seem relevant to where you start the calls.

Comment: Asperi thanks! (It's not pure SwiftUI but solves the case)

Answer (score 4):

✅ You are looking for this modifier:

```
.onWillAppear { /* Your code */ }
```

That can be achieved by implementing this simple extension using a custom modifier:

```
extension View {
    func onWillAppear(_ perform: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(WillAppearModifier(callback: perform))
    }
}

struct WillAppearModifier: ViewModifier {
    let callback: () -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(UIViewLifeCycleHandler(onWillAppear: callback))
    }
}
```

And bridging the viewController lifecycle to the SwiftUI like:

```
struct UIViewLifeCycleHandler: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController

    var onWillAppear: () -> Void = { }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIViewControllerType {
        context.coordinator
    }

    func updateUIViewController(
        _: UIViewControllerType,
        context _: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>
    ) { }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Self.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(onWillAppear: onWillAppear)
    }

    class Coordinator: UIViewControllerType {
        let onWillAppear: () -> Void

        init(onWillAppear: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.onWillAppear = onWillAppear
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }

        required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            onWillAppear()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can implement any other method you want this way.

Answer (score -8):

Try this modifier:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
            // your code
        }
```

Comment: `willEnterForegroundNotification` is not the same as `viewWillAppear`