# Is there a way to know if a view has already been loaded in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to focus the `isUsernameFocused` textField as soon as it loads on the screen, I tried doing it directly in the `onAppear` method but it looks like it needs a delay in order for it to focus. My concern is that for some reason the focus only occurs with a delay greater than 0.6 fractions of a second. Setting it at `0.7` fractions of a second seems to work fine but I'm afraid that eventually, this will stop working if the view gets bigger since it will need more time to load.

Is there a way to know when the `VStack` is fully loaded so I can trigger the `isUsernameFocused`? Something like, `viewDidLoad` in UIKit.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var isUsernameFocused: Bool
    @State private var username = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($isUsernameFocused)
        }
        .onAppear{
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7){
                self.isUsernameFocused = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to its nature SwiftUI does not give exact info about this. Use injected UIKit-based viewDidAppear. This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746380/12299030.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, UIKit viewDidLoad is the same as in SwiftUI view creating, ie equivalent is just ContentView()

Comment: this is not necessary because SwiftUI has its own life cycle, you can read about it [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear)

Comment: What's not necessary? There is no `onLoad` method in SwiftUI. As @Asperi said, due to the nature of SwiftUI the onLoad method is not available in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on macOS or tvOS you can use [prefersDefaultFocus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Button/prefersDefaultFocus(_:in:)) for that. It should come to iOS in June.

In the meantime, I just created this example that works around the issue. If your form appears multiple times you might want to check other values before setting the focus.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct FocusTestView : View {
    @State var presented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click Me") {
            presented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presented) {
            LoginForm()
        }
    }
}

struct LoginForm : View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case usernameField
        case passwordField
    }

    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .usernameField)

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .passwordField)

            Button("Sign In") {
                if username.isEmpty {
                    focusedField = .usernameField
                } else if password.isEmpty {
                    focusedField = .passwordField
                } else {
                //    handleLogin(username, password)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .uiKitOnAppear {
            focusedField = .usernameField
        }
    }
}

struct UIKitAppear: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let action: () -> Void
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIAppearViewController {
       let vc = UIAppearViewController()
        vc.action = action
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIAppearViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

class UIAppearViewController: UIViewController {
    var action: () -> Void = {}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.addSubview(UILabel())
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now()) { [weak self] in
            self?.action()
        }
        
    }
}
public extension View {
    func uiKitOnAppear(_ perform: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(UIKitAppear(action: perform))
    }
}
```

`UIKitAppear` was taken from [dev forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655338?page=2) and I added the dispatch async to call the action. `LoginForm` is from the docs on [FocusState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate).

Comment: @ malhal - How does that differ from the existing `.focused()` method? Would it focus as soon as the parent view load or how would that work? Sorry if I'm not seeing the obvious.

Comment: I added a workaround you could try